Albertville 1992 Winter Olympic Opening Ceremony Transcript Wanted
I am having trouble with transcribing Christophe Salengro's poems from the Albertville 1992 Winter Olympic Opening Ceremony. I have scoured the Internet looking for a premade transcription, and nothing has worked for the Parade of Nations. I have tried Wikipedia, the Olympic World Library, the LA84 Digital Library, etc, to no avail. I have been told to look for context clues to determine number, but Salengro's fast speech has made it difficult for me to find them. If you need the video, use this: Albertville 1992 - Opening Ceremony There, the parade starts at 15:00.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Here's a very simple way to focus on a problematic French text with accompanying research AND a definite question fit for fr.SE AND NOT a request for translation (which would be off-topic here): provide your own attempt to transcribe the poems and ask for improvements.

Il régresse and ils régressent are pronounced exactly the same so there is no way to deduce which one is said from hearing it. Only the context can help to figure it out.
Let's say it is very similar to the issue we might have to transcript 'my cousin' to French as it can be either mon cousin or ma cousine.

I just used that as an example.

That was the only question that matched StackExchange model and you now removed it:  Don't ask about: - Proofreading or translation, unless a specific source of concern is clearly specified
